# Spring Integration Module that Continuously Polls SFTP Stalled

Tags: java, spring-integration, jsch, spring-integration-sftp

I have an application which uses spring integration to poll the sftp and once it finds new file thats when spring batch kicks-in and processes the file. I have five such jobs written in an application which polls sftp (attached the code snippet of configuration of one module). I checked the JVM process is running on EC2 instance. There was no anomaly in the cpu usage I have also attached the application logs and the sftp logs of the server.

Here's sequence of events (All events in UTC timezone & date is 2023-05-08)

1. Client uploaded file on SFTP at 00:28:00
2. Application reads it
3. Application last log printed at 00:29:52.032
4. Application stalled indefinitely
5. Application restarted at 04:59:35.098

I am wondering why did the application abruptly freeze?

**Footnotes:**
Even though I am using JSCH-0.1.55 library, I saw that JSch class has version of '0.1.54' written inside it. This is the reason why I see 'Client=SSH-2.0-JSCH-0.1.54' in SFTP logs. I hope this should not be crux of the problem.

Checked the Profiler for the JVM and the EC2 instance. I have found no anomaly during the aforementioned timeline (attached picture). I have the feeling that there is something wrong with the JSch SFTP connection. Unfortunately, I am unable to replicate the issue.

Appreciate any help around the issue. Be it replication or speculation.

**SFTP Server Logs:**

```
time(UTC)       User        Message
04:59:58    my-app-prod CONNECTED SourceIP=<poller-application-ip> 
04:59:56    my-app-prod DISCONNECTED
04:59:56    my-app-prod CONNECTED SourceIP=<poller-application-ip> 
04:59:53    my-app-prod DISCONNECTED
04:59:53    my-app-prod CONNECTED SourceIP=<poller-application-ip> 
00:29:54    my-app-prod DISCONNECTED
00:29:54    my-app-prod DISCONNECTED
00:29:54    my-app-prod DISCONNECTED
00:29:54    my-app-prod DISCONNECTED
00:29:54    my-app-prod DISCONNECTED
00:29:54    my-app-prod DISCONNECTED
00:29:52    my-app-prod CLOSE Path=/<censored>/project/xyz.txt BytesOut=715152263
00:28:33    my-app-prod OPEN Path=/<censored>/project/xyz.txt Mode=READ
00:28:32    my-app-prod DISCONNECTED
00:28:31    my-app-prod CONNECTED SourceIP=<poller-application-ip> 
00:28:29    my-app-prod DISCONNECTED
00:28:29    my-app-prod CONNECTED SourceIP=<poller-application-ip> 
00:28:26    my-app-prod DISCONNECTED
00:28:26    my-app-prod CONNECTED SourceIP=<poller-application-ip> 
00:28:24    client-app-prod DISCONNECTED
00:28:24    client-app-prod ERROR Message="Access denied"
00:28:23    client-app-prod CLOSE Path=/<censored>/project/191544.txt BytesIn=715152263
00:28:23    my-app-prod DISCONNECTED
00:28:22    my-app-prod CONNECTED SourceIP=<poller-application-ip> 
00:28:20    my-app-prod DISCONNECTED
00:28:20    my-app-prod CONNECTED SourceIP=<poller-application-ip> 
00:28:17    my-app-prod DISCONNECTED
00:28:17    my-app-prod CONNECTED SourceIP=<poller-application-ip> 
00:28:14    my-app-prod DISCONNECTED
00:28:14    my-app-prod CONNECTED SourceIP=<poller-application-ip> 
00:28:11    my-app-prod DISCONNECTED
00:28:11    my-app-prod CONNECTED SourceIP=<poller-application-ip> 
00:28:08    my-app-prod DISCONNECTED
00:28:08    my-app-prod CONNECTED SourceIP=<poller-application-ip> 
00:28:05    my-app-prod DISCONNECTED
00:28:04    my-app-prod CONNECTED SourceIP=<poller-application-ip> 
00:28:02    my-app-prod DISCONNECTED
00:28:01    my-app-prod CONNECTED SourceIP=<poller-application-ip> 
00:28:00    client-app-prod OPEN Path=/<censored>/project/xyz.txt Mode=CREATE|TRUNCATE|WRITE
00:28:00    client-app-prod CONNECTED SourceIP=<client-ip> 
00:27:58    my-app-prod DISCONNECTED
00:27:58    my-app-prod CONNECTED SourceIP=<poller-application-ip> 
00:27:55    my-app-prod DISCONNECTED
00:27:55    my-app-prod CONNECTED SourceIP=<poller-application-ip> 
00:27:53    my-app-prod DISCONNECTED
00:27:52    my-app-prod CONNECTED SourceIP=<poller-application-ip> 
00:27:50    my-app-prod DISCONNECTED
00:27:49    my-app-prod CONNECTED SourceIP=<poller-application-ip> 
00:27:47    my-app-prod DISCONNECTED
00:27:46    my-app-prod CONNECTED SourceIP=<poller-application-ip> 
00:27:44    my-app-prod DISCONNECTED
```

**Java Application Logs (Reverse Chronology)**

```java
00:29:52.032 [Thread Id = 71] INFO com.example.apis.trigger.SFTPConfig:154 - Batch Triggered.
00:28:31.852 [Thread Id = 71] INFO com.jcraft.jsch:54 - Disconnecting from <PROD-SFTP-CENSORED> port 22
00:28:29.496 [Thread Id = 71] INFO com.jcraft.jsch:54 - Authentication succeeded (publickey).
00:28:29.430 [Thread Id = 71] INFO com.jcraft.jsch:54 - Next authentication method: publickey
00:28:29.430 [Thread Id = 71] INFO com.jcraft.jsch:54 - Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
00:28:29.409 [Thread Id = 71] INFO com.jcraft.jsch:54 - SSH_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
00:28:29.396 [Thread Id = 71] INFO com.jcraft.jsch:54 - SSH_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
00:28:29.396 [Thread Id = 71] INFO com.jcraft.jsch:54 - SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS received
00:28:29.396 [Thread Id = 71] INFO com.jcraft.jsch:54 - SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
00:28:29.396 [Thread Id = 71] INFO com.jcraft.jsch:54 - Host '<PROD-SFTP-CENSORED>' is known and matches the RSA host key
00:28:29.396 [Thread Id = 71] INFO com.jcraft.jsch:54 - ssh_rsa_verify: signature true
00:28:29.380 [Thread Id = 71] INFO com.jcraft.jsch:54 - expecting SSH_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
00:28:29.380 [Thread Id = 71] INFO com.jcraft.jsch:54 - SSH_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT sent
00:28:29.378 [Thread Id = 71] INFO com.jcraft.jsch:54 - kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha2-256 none
00:28:29.378 [Thread Id = 71] INFO com.jcraft.jsch:54 - kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha2-256 none
00:28:29.378 [Thread Id = 71] INFO com.jcraft.jsch:54 - kex: client:
00:28:29.378 [Thread Id = 71] INFO com.jcraft.jsch:54 - kex: client: none
00:28:29.378 [Thread Id = 71] INFO com.jcraft.jsch:54 - kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
00:28:29.378 [Thread Id = 71] INFO com.jcraft.jsch:54 - kex: client: aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,aes192-ctr,aes192-cbc,aes256-ctr,aes256-cbc
00:28:29.378 [Thread Id = 71] INFO com.jcraft.jsch:54 - kex: client: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
00:28:29.378 [Thread Id = 71] INFO com.jcraft.jsch:54 - kex: client: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
00:28:29.378 [Thread Id = 71] INFO com.jcraft.jsch:54 - kex: server:
00:28:29.378 [Thread Id = 71] INFO com.jcraft.jsch:54 - kex: server: none,zlib@openssh.com
00:28:29.378 [Thread Id = 71] INFO com.jcraft.jsch:54 - kex: server: umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512
00:28:29.378 [Thread Id = 71] INFO com.jcraft.jsch:54 - kex: server: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
00:28:29.378 [Thread Id = 71] INFO com.jcraft.jsch:54 - kex: server: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
00:28:29.378 [Thread Id = 71] INFO com.jcraft.jsch:54 - kex: server: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256
00:28:29.378 [Thread Id = 71] INFO com.jcraft.jsch:54 - SSH_MSG_KEXINIT received
00:28:29.351 [Thread Id = 71] INFO com.jcraft.jsch:54 - SSH_MSG_KEXINIT sent
00:28:29.351 [Thread Id = 71] INFO com.jcraft.jsch:54 - CheckSignatures: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
00:28:29.341 [Thread Id = 71] INFO com.jcraft.jsch:54 - CheckKexes: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521
00:28:29.341 [Thread Id = 71] INFO com.jcraft.jsch:54 - CheckCiphers: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,arcfour,arcfour128,arcfour256
00:28:29.341 [Thread Id = 71] INFO com.jcraft.jsch:54 - Local version string: SSH-2.0-JSCH-0.1.54
00:28:29.341 [Thread Id = 71] INFO com.jcraft.jsch:54 - Remote version string: SSH-2.0-AWS_SFTP_1.1
00:28:29.275 [Thread Id = 71] INFO com.jcraft.jsch:54 - Connection established
00:28:29.261 [Thread Id = 71] INFO com.jcraft.jsch:54 - Connecting to <PROD-SFTP-CENSORED> port 22
00:28:29.261 [Thread Id = 141857] INFO com.jcraft.jsch:54 - Caught an exception, leaving main loop due to Socket closed
```

**Code Snippet:**

```java
public SessionFactory<LsEntry> xyzSFTPSessionFactory() {
    DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory(true);
    try {
        factory.setHost("abc");
        factory.setPort(22);
        factory.setUser("my-app-prod");
        factory.setPrivateKey(sftpPrivateKey);
        factory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
    } catch (SftpConnectionException se) {
        LOGGER.error("Exception occurred while creating ABC", se);
    }
        return new CachingSessionFactory<>(factory);
}


@InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "xyzStream")
    public MessageSource<InputStream> xyzSFTPMessageSource() {
        SftpStreamingMessageSource mSource = new SftpStreamingMessageSource(xyzTemplate());
        mSource.setRemoteDirectory(xyzRemoteDirectory);
        mSource.setFilter(new AcceptAllFileListFilter<>());
        mSource.setMaxFetchSize(1);
        return mSource;
    }
```

Comment: The fact that you see `SSH-2.0-JSCH-0.1.54` might be just because the library didn't update that string in the code. It look like you use a gateway somewhere downstream where a reply is not expected. So, this gateway is stuck waiting for reply therefore blocking the thread. I also see `Caught an exception, leaving main loop due to Socket closed` - would be great to have more info around that error.

Comment: Thank you @ArtemBilan for your prompt response. Indeed there is a functionality where we have used MessagingGateway thats for moving file from one folder to another based on the status of processing. Artem, just to highlight that I see `Caught an exception, leaving main loop due to Socket closed` regularly in the logs and I thought that its a part of regular JSch flow so it won't cause application freeze. But since you have pointed it out. I will look into it.